# How to console log data from observable subscription?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a simple function, included in a service, returning an observable of an object:

```
 private someData;

 getDataStream(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of(this.someData);
  }
```

I subscribe to this function onInit of a component:

```
  private somethingsomething;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getDataStream().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.somethingsomething = data; // WORKS AND ALWAYS UP TO DATE
        console.log(data); // ONLY WORKS ONCE
      }
    )
  }
```

As commented, the data when given to a variable, which is then displayed in the view, is always fine. But the console.log on the other hand is only triggered once, and then never again.

How can I console.log the data whenever it changes?

Comment: depends on how you are using it in the view. Can you provide some information on that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code. Works well.

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getDataStream().subscribe(
        res => {
        this.somethingsomething = res ;
            console.log(res);
          });     
      }
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `this.somethingsomething` changes is that it has the reference of `someData`. `getDataStream` method gets executed only once. But since the object changes, the field with that reference `somethingsomething`s value also changes. This is because `Object`s are mutable in javascript.

If `getDataStream` was returning a response from a server, that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: I see, so my whole subscribtion is useless. Any hint on how to do it correctly? :)

Comment: @JakobFischer well that's really broad but this can only happen if you do an assignment to the object. Where are you making the assignments? You can maybe use a publish/subscribe pattern. That is, only change the object from a method and whenever this method is used you can log it.

Answer (score 0):

To log this data to the console it's best to use the `do` operator. Every time a new value is pushed from the `getDataStream` observable the `do` operator will console.log that data.

```
 private somethingsomething;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getDataStream()
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.somethingsomething = data;
      }
    )
  }
```